# Cannot map JSON array into list of objects with GSON

Tags: java, gson

I have the following json sting in a String

```
[
    "{\"eventType\":\"getcontent\",\"id\":\"1\"}\n",
    "{\"eventType\":\"getcontent\",\"id\":\"2\"}\n"
]
```

I want to map this into my java class:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class LogRequest {

    private String eventType;

    private String id;
}
```

Like this:

```
List<LogRequest> lastMonthEvents = new ArrayList<>();
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<LogRequest>>() {}.getType();
lastMonthEvents.addAll(gson.fromJson(text, listType));
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

How can I map this json array into a list of java objects?

Comment: The error message is clear. Array elements are not objects, but strings. "{\"eventType\":\"getcontent\",\"id\":\"1\"}\n", make this string into a JSON Object.

Comment: Problem in you json. If its a typo, update question!